# interaction with objects in xna

Tags: class, xna, collision

I'm new to using xna and I want to make my player collide with with multipe walls from the same class. So I looked around and I understood that the best way for doing that is to create a list of variables containing the walls id's and make a loop that circles them all and then returns the variable of the objects that collide.
My question is if there is a faster more efficient way for doing that? I mean if I have like 10000 objects that loop can cause a lot of memory use. 
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Option 1) If these 10000 object are walls of a level, then you should probably use some sort of grid (like this very old example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda#mediaviewer/File:Legend_of_Zelda_NES.PNG)
With a grid you only have to check collision with adjacent objects, or only with objects that are nearby.

Option 2) If these 10000 objects are enemies or bullets that move more freely, then you could also calculate the distance first and only check for collision if the objects are nearby.

But may I ask why you are using XNA? I used to work with XNA 4.x but in my understanding it is pretty much dead (http://www.computerandvideogames.com/389018/microsoft-email-confirms-plan-to-cease-xna-support). If you're new to XNA, I would advice to use other software to make games (like Unity3D). In Unity3D the hard part of collision detection is done for you (is has standard functions for collision detection) and Unity3D also works with C# (like XNA)

Comment: First of all thx for the help :) and I started using it after playing Dust:aet. Didnt know it was dead tough lol, ill check unity and see how it is. Thx again

Comment: XNA is framework, Unity is game engine. If you wish to understand how game works and to have control over every part then you use XNA, but if you just wish to make a game then use unity where you can just drag 'n' drop assets and functions.

Comment: +1 for the options given, but not for advising not using XNA anymore. He could be using Monogame and if that's the case, then XNA is a good option. Also, as Davor said, Unity is an engine, meaning you wont be able to learn like you would with XNA.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric `DirectX` is an API; XNA is framework; Unity is game engine. If you wish to understand how game works and to have control over every part then you use **DirectX** for at least it is still relevant today and `not dead` like **XNA** is.  However, being COM and C++ based is very hard.  Your next best option is `Unity3D`.  It's also way more cross-platform than Monogame

Comment: All of you are absolutely right noting the difference between XNA and Unity (and DirectX). It was because of stav12212's question I thought of him a bit of a beginner (in game development, not in programming) and apparently he's capable of using C#. These are the reasons I advised Unity and did not elaborate on differences (and it is possible to do pretty much anything with C# in Unity -you can avoid most of the drag 'n drop).

Comment: @User52784246 Unity3D for speed and convenience (for quick money :/); XNA good for learning cause it's put and you should do all by yourself; DirectX for performance maniacs. And if XNA is dead it is not important for learning. I think XNA is good for begining if you want to understand ho all this s**t works.

Comment: Xna is perfect if it gets the job done. But plain old XNA is not supported on windows8+ which is a bummer. C# is awesome and XNA still is an awesome framework.

Answer (score 0):

You always want to do the least amount of processing to get the job done. For a tiled 2D game you usually have a 2 dimensional grid. When the player want to walk on a certain tile you can check that tile if it is allowed to walk there. In this case you just have to check a single tile. If you have a lot of NPC's you could divide your map into sections and keep track of in what sections the NPC's are. Now you just have to do collision detection on the enemies within your section.

When you need expensive collision, pixel perfect or polygon collision you should first check if an object is even close with a simple radius `float` or `BoundingSphere` only then you go on with more expensive collision detection.

Same goes for pretty much anything, if you have a 100x100 tilemap but only need to draw 20x10 for the screen then you should just render that portion by calculations. In unreal, mappers create invisible boxes, when inside these boxes it only draws a certain part of the map and only checks collision within these boxes. GameDev is all about tricks to make things work smoothly.